# How to uninstall an Application in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, uninstall

Now there are two different types of applications (Modern UI and Desktop) and I'm wondering how to uninstall them now? Does the old "add/remove Application" still work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both Desktop and Modern UI applications can be uninstalled via the new Start Menu by opening the options bar (right click on the application you want to uninstall):

[image]

In case of a **Modern UI application**, a confirmation dialog appears and after clicking `Uninstall` the application is uninstalled.

In case of a **Desktop application**, the old `Programs and Features` dialog will open where you need to select your application and choose to uninstall. Then the familiar uninstall process starts.

The `Programs and Features` application to uninstall desktop applications is still available in the Control Panel.

Comment: you can also use add/remove programs.  It's found in the Settings section of the Start Screen.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the "Control Panel" like in Windows 7 and go to "Unistall a program". This is only for desktop programs though.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, then type in `appwiz.cpl` for a traditional uninstall.